# Set debugging macro conditionally with make

Tags: c++, build, debugging, makefile, macros

In my C++ project, I have a convention where whenever the macro `DEBUG` is defined, debugging printf-esque statements are compiled into the executable.

To indicate whether or not I want these compiled into the executable, I normally would pass the macro name to gcc with the `-D`*macro* option.  So, in the `Makefile` I (currently) have:

```
CXXFLAGS += -g -I ../ -Wall -Werror -DDEBUG
```

However, this is not very flexible;  if I didn't want debug statements in my final program, I'd have to modify the Makefile to remove the -DDEBUG.

Is there a way to modify the `Makefile` such that I can conditionally select whether to compile with -D in the CXXFLAGS at compile time by passing in, say, another target name or a commandline switch?  Not sure how'd I go about doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can conditionally define other variables based on the target in the makefile.

```
all:    target
debug:  target

debug:  DEBUG=PLOP

target:
        @echo "HI $(DEBUG)"
```

So now:

```
> make
HI
>
> make debug
HI PLOP
>
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Append another variable that you can set from the CLI or environment

```
$ cat Makefile
CXXFLAGS += $(CLIFLAGS)

maintarget:
    echo $(CXXFLAGS)
$ make CLIFLAGS=-DDEBUG
echo -DDEBUG
-DDEBUG
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this one:
http://users.softlab.ece.ntua.gr/~ttsiod/makefile.html

Answer (score 0):

After meditating upon the [make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Testing-Flags),  I tried putting this in my Makefile:

```
ifneq(,$(findstring d,$(MAKEFLAGS)))
CXXFLAGS += <... all normal options ...> -DDEBUG
else
CXXFLAGS += <... all normal options ...>
endif
```

Then, when you run `make -d`, `-DDEBUG` is set.

Now, mind you, it works, but I had to use a normal flag that make usually accepts (you can't make up your own). Using -d also spews (harmless) verbose make-level debugging statements to the screen.  Which I really don't want; it obscures compile errors.  But it does work.

I hope someone can come up with a better idea.

Comment: Amro's link has a variation on this idea, which is better than mine.